# How to replace the groupByKey with reduceByKey to return as an Iterable value in Spark java?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a spark java program where a groupByKey with a mapValues step is done and it returns a PairRDD with value as an `Iterable` of all the input rdd values. 
I have read that replacing reduceByKey in the place of groupByKey with mapValues will give a performance gain, but i don't know how to apply `reduceByKey` to my problem here.

Specifically i have the an input pair RDD which has value with type `Tuple5`. After the groupByKey and mapValues transformations, i need to get a Key-Value pair RDD where the value needs to be an Iterable of the input values.

```
JavaPairRDD<Long,Tuple5<...>> inputRDD;
...
...
...
JavaPairRDD<Long, Iterable<Tuple5<...>>> groupedRDD = inputRDD
    .groupByKey()
    .mapValues(
            new Function<Iterable<Tuple5<...>>,Iterable<Tuple5<...>>>() {

                @Override
                public Iterable<Tuple5<...>> call(
                        Iterable<Tuple5<...>> v1)
                        throws Exception {

                    /*
                    Some steps here..                               
                    */

                    return mappedValue;
                }
            });
```

Is there a way by which i could get the above transformation using `reduceByKey`?

Comment: What are `Some steps here`? You'll need a logic to reduce it with.

Comment: In the `mapValues` function i am actually sorting each value based on a key within `Tuple5`. I thought it wasn't relevant here, that's why i didn't include them.

Comment: _I have read that replacing reduceByKey in the place of groupByKey with mapValues will give a performance gain_ -  you've read wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Scala on Spark, so this isn't going to be the exact answer you might prefer.  The main difference in coding between `groupByKey/mapValues` and `reduceByKey` can be seen using a trivial example adapted from this [article](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html):

```
val words = Array("one", "two", "two", "three", "three", "three")
val wordPairsRDD = sc.parallelize(words).map(word => (word, 1))

val wordCountsWithGroup = wordPairsRDD.
  groupByKey.
  mapValues(_.sum)
wordCountsWithGroup.collect
res1: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((two,2), (one,1), (three,3))

val wordCountsWithReduce = wordPairsRDD.
  reduceByKey(_ + _)
wordCountsWithReduce.collect
res2: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((two,2), (one,1), (three,3))
```

In this example, where `x => x.sum` (i.e. _.sum) is used in `mapValues`, it'll be `(acc, x) => acc + x` (i.e. _ + _) in `reduceByKey`.  The function signatures are vastly different.  In `mapValues`, you're processing a collection of the grouped values, whereas in `reduceByKey` you're performing a reduction.

Comment: From what i understand, in order to get an grouped list of a pair RDD, i will always need to use `groupKey` because `reduceByKey` is meant for aggregate operations like sum. So in my case, `reduceByKey` isn't possible right?

Comment: After re-reading your description in the question's comment section, I'd say `groupByKey` is probably the way to go, as I don't think reduction is a right tool for the task.